# Do English alphabet come under latin characters?

Tags: alphabet

I haven't been able to infer whether latin characters are different from English alphabet or English alphabet are a subset of latin characters, as I came across several versions of latin.

Trying to find an answer as one of the driving rules of a foreign country says details on license should be in latin characters, so I am wondering whether my information printed in English qualifies for being in Latin?

Comment: Yes, what is typically referred to as the "English alphabet" also qualifies as Latin characters

Comment: @sumelic Cool, thanks for confirming! You can post that as an answer if you are certain so that I can accept it.

Comment: "I am wondering whether my information printed in English qualifies for being in Latin?" Well, no: English and Latin are two different languages, albeit using character sets/alphabets which are practically identical.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well may be not the same on a semantic level but it does mean information printed as "Ashish Kumar" qualifies for being in Latin, which is what it seems like from links provided by sumelic. Correct?

Comment: No: you are confusing the latin alphabet with the Latin language.

Comment: Umm I am not sure. What does "printed in Latin" means? Latin alphabets right? And that would mean my information printed in English is OK?

Comment: What do you mean by “English alphabets”? In general usage, there is only one English alphabet (consisting of the letters A–Z). Are you including things like Braille? If so, then no—the letters used in Braille are not Latin characters. “Printed in Latin” means printed in the Latin language. There is no exact definition of what ‘Latin characters’ are, but if that’s what it says you should use, it’s most likely that it means the [ISO Basic Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet), which is identical to the English alphabet, but specifically excluding diacritics.

Comment: Since this appears to be about information for an Indian license, it seems most likely that they are expecting you to write your name transliterated into Latin characters, probably with no diacritics. That means that you should not write अाशीष कुमर (or however exactly you’d write it) in Devanāgarī. You probably also shouldn’t write _Āśīṣ Kumar_ (as some transliteration schemes would represent it), since that contains fairly advanced diacritics. _Ashish Kumar_ is probably what is intended.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes I meant alphabet (singular) and that answers my question ✌️